# Addint lat/lon data to scrollview in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, coordinates

I have created a custom map (jpg) for an iOS app I am working on. I have the large image displayed in a scroll view.

I already have the lat/lon for all four corners of the image but I am not sure how how to convert the known locations in a way that I can draw labels on certain locations of the map. The label locations are based on lat/lon so I would need a way to convert the lat lon into a x/y coordinate to display an object on the image in the app.

I have looked for info on this but everything I found dealt more with obtaining the know lat/lon as opposed to implementing it in the app.

(the map is an area about the size of Texas)

Would appreciate any guidance

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to get the lat/lon numbers, subtract them, know the exact drawing rate and convert it to pixels. There's no other way. A better suggestion is to use Google Maps in your app, will save much work for you, instead of JPG. This will require being online though..

Answer (score 0):

After reading your questions a couple of times, I still do not know what you are trying to do. But here is some tips for converting

say your jpg image has the (lat,lng) of (a,b) to (c,d)
and pixel of (width,height)

so to get (lat,lng) from (x,y) you use

```
lat = a + x/width*(c-a);
lng = b + y/height*(d-b);
```

Now make sure you are using the same coordinate system. If not, say your pixel starts from lower left instead of top left, then just invert it.

```
lat = a + x/width*(c-a);
lng = b + (height - y)/height*(d-b);
```

Same goes for converting x and y from lat and lng. Just reverse the formula above. 
Now you need to look up stuff from Google using their reverse geocoding API. Unless you prefer something else, here is some snippet:

```
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=true", lat, lng];
NSData *dataFromServer = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
```

dataFromServer contains JSON infomation about the thing you are trying to look up. Parse it however you need to.

Is this what you are looking for?